# Possible VBA AND Operator Anomaly

Tags: vba, excel, logical-operators, defects

On my 32-Bit PC, running Office 2003 Excel VBA, the following code

```
Debug.Print ""
Debug.Print Hex(&HFF00000 And &HF00000)
Debug.Print Hex(&HFF0000 And &HF0000)
Debug.Print Hex(&HFF000 And &HF000)
Debug.Print Hex(&HFF00 And &HF00)
Debug.Print Hex(&HFF0 And &HF0)
Debug.Print Hex(&HFF And &HF)
```

gives the following Output

```
F00000
F0000
FF000   '<- Here's the Anomaly 
F00
F0
F
```

This Only seems to occur with the Hex Value "F"; ie substitute all the "F"'s with any other Hex Digit and the Output will be as expected

Looks like some hangover from 16-Bit processing

My world has been shattered

I'm wondering if;

1) this really is an Anomaly (or am I going mad?)

if it is;

2) does it occur with other Office Versions

3) does it occur on 64-Bit PCs

4) what's the most elegant work-around

Any clues would be appreciated

Comment: FYI: same behaviour occurs on 64-bit version of office 2010

Comment: `Debug.Print &HF000, CLng(&HF000), CLng("&HF000")` gives `-4096    -4096   61440` so seems related to the "bare" `&h` notation...

Comment: For large hex numbers in VBA you need to append `&` (the long type character) to ensure it gets stored correctly as a long. E.g. try this `Debug.Print &HF000,  &HF000&`

Comment: @Tim You should post this as an answer.  That VBA treats `&H` values as signed, and values <= `&HFFFF` as 16 bit signed integer and quoted values as unsigned are really interesting results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For large hex numbers in VBA you need to append `&` (the long type character) to ensure it gets stored correctly as a long.

E.g. try this

```
Debug.Print &HF000, &HF000&
```

Comment: Nice one; thank you Tim. Interesting to note that my Excel VBA complier automatically removes the trailing "&" from Hex values greater than &HFFF& eg Debug.Print Hex(&HFF000 And &HF000&) in the above example